# install Rpy2 on mac Yosemite, but get error

Tags: python, macos, rpy2

I tried to install Rpy2 on mac Yosemite, but got error. What's worse, I can understand the error.

I just wanna install rpy2 with pip3 for python3.6.

Following is (part of) the error. Do you need more details?

I knew someone asked similar questions, but it was not helpful.

```
$ pip3 install rpy2
Collecting rpy2
  Using cached rpy2-2.8.6.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from rpy2)
Building wheels for collected packages: rpy2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for rpy2 ... error
  Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/md/8kgtqqz12j94hbcvhqz0w7gw0000gp/T/pip-build-9yh0e2ml/rpy2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /var/folders/md/8kgtqqz12j94hbcvhqz0w7gw0000gp/T/tmp2fvzaznqpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"
  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD config --ldflags
  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD config --cppflags

      Compilation parameters for rpy2's C components:
          include_dirs    = ['/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include']
          library_dirs    = ['/usr/local/lib']
          libraries       = ['pcre', 'lzma', 'bz2', 'z', 'icucore', 'm', 'iconv']
          extra_link_args = ['-fopenmp', '-F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/..', '-framework', 'R']

  running bdist_wheel

 ...... (thousands words are omitted here)


  /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -I./rpy/rinterface -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -c ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.o
  ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:230:40: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'malloc' with type 'void *(unsigned long)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    ExternallyManagedVector *extvector = malloc(sizeof(ExternallyManagedVector));
                                         ^
  ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:230:40: note: include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'malloc'
  1 warning generated.
  ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:230:40: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'malloc' with type 'void *(unsigned long)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    ExternallyManagedVector *extvector = malloc(sizeof(ExternallyManagedVector));
                                         ^
  ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:230:40: note: include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'malloc'
  1 warning generated.
  ar rc build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/libr_utils.a build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.o
  ranlib build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/libr_utils.a
  running build_ext
  R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"
  building 'rpy2.rinterface._rinterface' extension
  /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DR_INTERFACE_PTRS=1 -DHAVE_POSIX_SIGJMP=1 -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND=1 -DCSTACK_DEFNS=1 -DHAS_READLINE=1 -I./rpy/rinterface -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o
  In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:52:
  In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:8:
  In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R.h:81:
  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/Rconfig.h:20:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_SIZE_T' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
  #define SIZEOF_SIZE_T 8
          ^
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m/pymacconfig.h:56:17: note: previous definition is here
  #        define SIZEOF_SIZE_T           4
                  ^
  In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:98:
  ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:6:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
  extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED;
                            ^
  ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:7:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
  extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY;
                            ^
  In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:116:
  ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:5:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
  const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED = 0x01;
                     ^
  ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:6:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
  const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY = 0x02;
                     ^
  ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:48:12: warning: unused variable 'res' [-Wunused-variable]
        SEXP res = rpy2_remove(Rf_mkString(name_buf),
             ^
  In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:119:
  ./rpy/rinterface/sexp.c:742:13: warning: unused variable 'copy' [-Wunused-variable]
    PyObject *copy = Py_True;
              ^
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:347:3: warning: variable 'consolecallback' is used uninitialized whenever switch default is taken [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
    default:
    ^~~~~~~
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:373:7: note: uninitialized use occurs here
    if (consolecallback == NULL) {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:339:24: note: initialize the variable 'consolecallback' to silence this warning
    void *consolecallback;
                         ^
                          = NULL
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:1808:21: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'const char *' from 'SEXP' (aka 'struct SEXPREC *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        argNameString = Rf_mkCharCE(PyBytes_AsString(pybytes), CE_UTF8);
                      ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:1809:32: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'SEXP' (aka 'struct SEXPREC *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        SET_TAG(c_R, installChar(argNameString));
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/Rinternals.h:855:25: note: passing argument to parameter here
  SEXP Rf_installChar(SEXP);
                          ^
  In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:52:
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:203:44: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_IsInitialized' [-Wunused-function]
    static PyRinterface_IsInitialized_RETURN PyRinterface_IsInitialized PyRinterface_IsInitialized_PROTO;
                                             ^
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:204:38: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_FindFun' [-Wunused-function]
    static PyRinterface_FindFun_RETURN PyRinterface_FindFun PyRinterface_FindFun_PROTO;
                                       ^
  In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:122:
  ./rpy/rinterface/sequence.c:2173:1: warning: unused function 'ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp' [-Wunused-function]
  ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp(PyObject *pyfloat) {
  ^
  13 warnings generated.
  In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:98:
  ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:6:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
  extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED;
                            ^
  ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:7:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
  extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY;
                            ^
  In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:116:
  ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:5:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
  const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED = 0x01;
                     ^
  ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:6:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
  const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY = 0x02;
                     ^
  ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:48:12: warning: unused variable 'res' [-Wunused-variable]
        SEXP res = rpy2_remove(Rf_mkString(name_buf),
             ^
  In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:119:
  ./rpy/rinterface/sexp.c:742:13: warning: unused variable 'copy' [-Wunused-variable]
    PyObject *copy = Py_True;
              ^
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:347:3: warning: variable 'consolecallback' is used uninitialized whenever switch default is taken [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
    default:
    ^~~~~~~
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:373:7: note: uninitialized use occurs here
    if (consolecallback == NULL) {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:339:24: note: initialize the variable 'consolecallback' to silence this warning
    void *consolecallback;
                         ^
                          = NULL
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:1808:21: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'const char *' from 'SEXP' (aka 'struct SEXPREC *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        argNameString = Rf_mkCharCE(PyBytes_AsString(pybytes), CE_UTF8);
                      ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:1809:32: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'SEXP' (aka 'struct SEXPREC *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        SET_TAG(c_R, installChar(argNameString));
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/Rinternals.h:855:25: note: passing argument to parameter here
  SEXP Rf_installChar(SEXP);
                          ^
  In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:52:
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:203:44: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_IsInitialized' [-Wunused-function]
    static PyRinterface_IsInitialized_RETURN PyRinterface_IsInitialized PyRinterface_IsInitialized_PROTO;
                                             ^
  ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:204:38: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_FindFun' [-Wunused-function]
    static PyRinterface_FindFun_RETURN PyRinterface_FindFun PyRinterface_FindFun_PROTO;
                                       ^
  In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:122:
  ./rpy/rinterface/sequence.c:2173:1: warning: unused function 'ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp' [-Wunused-function]
  ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp(PyObject *pyfloat) {
  ^
  12 warnings generated.
  /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o -L/usr/local/lib -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6 -L/usr/local/lib -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -licucore -lm -liconv -lr_utils -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so -fopenmp -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R
  clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
  clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for rpy2
  Running setup.py clean for rpy2
Failed to build rpy2
Installing collected packages: rpy2
  Running setup.py install for rpy2 ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/md/8kgtqqz12j94hbcvhqz0w7gw0000gp/T/pip-build-9yh0e2ml/rpy2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/md/8kgtqqz12j94hbcvhqz0w7gw0000gp/T/pip-22abu_x8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD config --ldflags
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD config --cppflags

        Compilation parameters for rpy2's C components:
            include_dirs    = ['/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include']
            library_dirs    = ['/usr/local/lib']
            libraries       = ['pcre', 'lzma', 'bz2', 'z', 'icucore', 'm', 'iconv']
            extra_link_args = ['-fopenmp', '-F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/..', '-framework', 'R']

    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/rpy2
    ......  (thousands words are omitted here)
    copying ./rpy/ipython/tests/test_rmagic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/rpy2/ipython/tests
    running build_clib
    building 'r_utils' library
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/rpy
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/rpy/rinterface
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -I./rpy/rinterface -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -c ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.o
    ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:230:40: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'malloc' with type 'void *(unsigned long)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      ExternallyManagedVector *extvector = malloc(sizeof(ExternallyManagedVector));
                                           ^
    ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:230:40: note: include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'malloc'
    1 warning generated.
    ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:230:40: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'malloc' with type 'void *(unsigned long)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      ExternallyManagedVector *extvector = malloc(sizeof(ExternallyManagedVector));
                                           ^
    ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:230:40: note: include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'malloc'
    1 warning generated.
    ar rc build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/libr_utils.a build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.o
    ranlib build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/libr_utils.a
    running build_ext
    R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"
    building 'rpy2.rinterface._rinterface' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DR_INTERFACE_PTRS=1 -DHAVE_POSIX_SIGJMP=1 -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND=1 -DCSTACK_DEFNS=1 -DHAS_READLINE=1 -I./rpy/rinterface -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:52:
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:8:
    In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R.h:81:
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/Rconfig.h:20:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_SIZE_T' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
    #define SIZEOF_SIZE_T 8
            ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m/pymacconfig.h:56:17: note: previous definition is here
    #        define SIZEOF_SIZE_T           4
                    ^
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:98:
    ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:6:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
    extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED;
                              ^
    ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:7:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
    extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY;
                              ^
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:116:
    ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:5:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
    const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED = 0x01;
                       ^
    ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:6:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
    const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY = 0x02;
                       ^
    ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:48:12: warning: unused variable 'res' [-Wunused-variable]
          SEXP res = rpy2_remove(Rf_mkString(name_buf),
               ^
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:119:
    ./rpy/rinterface/sexp.c:742:13: warning: unused variable 'copy' [-Wunused-variable]
      PyObject *copy = Py_True;
                ^
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:347:3: warning: variable 'consolecallback' is used uninitialized whenever switch default is taken [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
      default:
      ^~~~~~~
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:373:7: note: uninitialized use occurs here
      if (consolecallback == NULL) {
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:339:24: note: initialize the variable 'consolecallback' to silence this warning
      void *consolecallback;
                           ^
                            = NULL
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:1808:21: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'const char *' from 'SEXP' (aka 'struct SEXPREC *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
          argNameString = Rf_mkCharCE(PyBytes_AsString(pybytes), CE_UTF8);
                        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:1809:32: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'SEXP' (aka 'struct SEXPREC *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
          SET_TAG(c_R, installChar(argNameString));
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/Rinternals.h:855:25: note: passing argument to parameter here
    SEXP Rf_installChar(SEXP);
                            ^
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:52:
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:203:44: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_IsInitialized' [-Wunused-function]
      static PyRinterface_IsInitialized_RETURN PyRinterface_IsInitialized PyRinterface_IsInitialized_PROTO;
                                               ^
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:204:38: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_FindFun' [-Wunused-function]
      static PyRinterface_FindFun_RETURN PyRinterface_FindFun PyRinterface_FindFun_PROTO;
                                         ^
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:122:
    ./rpy/rinterface/sequence.c:2173:1: warning: unused function 'ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp' [-Wunused-function]
    ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp(PyObject *pyfloat) {
    ^
    13 warnings generated.
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:98:
    ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:6:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
    extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED;
                              ^
    ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:7:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
    extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY;
                              ^
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:116:
    ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:5:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
    const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED = 0x01;
                       ^
    ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:6:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
    const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY = 0x02;
                       ^
    ./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:48:12: warning: unused variable 'res' [-Wunused-variable]
          SEXP res = rpy2_remove(Rf_mkString(name_buf),
               ^
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:119:
    ./rpy/rinterface/sexp.c:742:13: warning: unused variable 'copy' [-Wunused-variable]
      PyObject *copy = Py_True;
                ^
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:347:3: warning: variable 'consolecallback' is used uninitialized whenever switch default is taken [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
      default:
      ^~~~~~~
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:373:7: note: uninitialized use occurs here
      if (consolecallback == NULL) {
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:339:24: note: initialize the variable 'consolecallback' to silence this warning
      void *consolecallback;
                           ^
                            = NULL
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:1808:21: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'const char *' from 'SEXP' (aka 'struct SEXPREC *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
          argNameString = Rf_mkCharCE(PyBytes_AsString(pybytes), CE_UTF8);
                        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:1809:32: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'SEXP' (aka 'struct SEXPREC *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
          SET_TAG(c_R, installChar(argNameString));
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/Rinternals.h:855:25: note: passing argument to parameter here
    SEXP Rf_installChar(SEXP);
                            ^
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:52:
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:203:44: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_IsInitialized' [-Wunused-function]
      static PyRinterface_IsInitialized_RETURN PyRinterface_IsInitialized PyRinterface_IsInitialized_PROTO;
                                               ^
    ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:204:38: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_FindFun' [-Wunused-function]
      static PyRinterface_FindFun_RETURN PyRinterface_FindFun PyRinterface_FindFun_PROTO;
                                         ^
    In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:122:
    ./rpy/rinterface/sequence.c:2173:1: warning: unused function 'ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp' [-Wunused-function]
    ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp(PyObject *pyfloat) {
    ^
    12 warnings generated.
    /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o -L/usr/local/lib -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6 -L/usr/local/lib -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -licucore -lm -liconv -lr_utils -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so -fopenmp -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R
    clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
    clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/md/8kgtqqz12j94hbcvhqz0w7gw0000gp/T/pip-build-9yh0e2ml/rpy2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/md/8kgtqqz12j94hbcvhqz0w7gw0000gp/T/pip-22abu_x8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/md/8kgtqqz12j94hbcvhqz0w7gw0000gp/T/pip-build-9yh0e2ml/rpy2/
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue your facing is related to the `Clang` compiler

`clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'`

Basically the clang installation on OSX is an Apple-customized version which doesn't have OpenMP support as of now. You can build your own clang (not advisable) or try to check if the build is possible with another compiler -> GCC

**Installing GCC:**

```
brew install gcc
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/
brew link --overwrite gcc
```

**Changing Compiler:**

```
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc;CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++;MPICXX=/usr/local/bin/mpicxx
```

Comment: sounds too simple. There are many other errors. Can i install gcc with homebrew?

Comment: I have installed gcc, it reported the same error still!

Comment: @WilliamSong I've updated the post with commands to install and configure gcc

Comment: In mac, gcc command works with a wrapper to clang. So we install gcc and forcibly change the gcc symlink to the new installation